# How can I switch the function in the sms webhook inside twilio console for another one in the console using Google sheet script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, twilio

I'm using a Twilio SMS webhook function to auto-respond to people texting my twilio number.

I want to switch this function for another one I already made in my console, using Google sheet script.

I just miss the part in JavaScript (Google Sheet script) to ask Twilio's console to switch the function used in the webhook for another one I made (also in the console).

I don't have any code yet because I just don't know how to reach this option. :(

I asked on a public twilio forum and they said to ask here.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update a Twilio number's SMS webhook with the Incoming Phone Number resource of our API as shown in the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource.

The property for the SMS webhook is SmsUrl​.

Since you can't use the Twilio Node.JS Helper Library in Google Sheets, you will have to create a function that POSTs to the incoming phone number endpoint like this:

function changeSMSUrl() {
  var incomingPhoneNumber_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/Your_Account_SID/IncomingPhoneNumbers/Your_Number_SID.json";

var payload = {
    "SmsUrl": "New_SMS_Webhook_URL"
  };

var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("Your_Account_SID:Your_Auth_Token")
  };

UrlFetchApp.fetch(incomingPhoneNumber_url, options);
}

NOTE: You will need to replace the following placeholders in the code above with your own values:

Your_Account_SID
Your_Number_SID
New_SMS_Webhook_URL
Your_Auth_Token